# Using UWSim GPS

Tags: ros, gps, rostopic, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am a beginner user of UWSim and I was trying to use the GPS sensor. I run "rosrun uwsim uwsim" and the scene with the robot in a tank loads up. I notice that there is a topic "/g500/gps" and I call "rostopic echo /g500/gps". However, this does not give any data. I tried changing the rate in the XML file but this does not have any effect.

How can I use the GPS sensor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205405/using-uwsim-gps/) by [raluse](https://answers.ros.org/users/21914/raluse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure your robot is floating on the surface, GPS doesn't work underwater!

---

Originally posted by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) with karma: 291 on 2015-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raluse](https://answers.ros.org/users/21914/raluse/) on 2015-03-19**:
Of course, haha. Thank you very much